# Objective-C: Instance variables may not be placed in categories

Tags: objective-c, subclass, nsobject

I am learning Objective-C and the tutorials I am watching are using an outdated version of Xcode. So, I am not sure whether I created a wrong type of class or if there is something wrong with the code.

In Xcode I Did Command+N do create a new file, clicked 'Source' under 'OS X' and clicked Objective-C File. Then I for file type I chose Category and class: NSObject. In the tutorial the guy made a subclass and since this was the only Objective-C related file in the new Xcode I decided to use this. After making the header and main files, I created the following text.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (Person){
    NSString *myName;
    NSNumber *myAge;
    NSNumber *myGrade;
}

@end
```

Thanks alot, Coler234

Comment: The version of Xcode has no connection with the syntax for a class declaration. You simply haven't followed the tutorial.

Comment: The error message is perfectly clear. You created a category and placed instance variables inside it. Categories are not allowed to have instance variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *category* is an extension of an existing class with some new methods. To indicate you are defining a category rather than a new class, follow the class name with the category name in parentheses as you did in your code`(Person)`. What you actually wanted, though, is a *subclass* of NSObject called Person, so you need to say

`@interface Person : NSObject`